# `[description](url)` - prepend by default `https://` if not protocol specified

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, markdown, hyperlinks, short-links

Using the inline link notation, `[SO](stackoverflow.com)`, results in:

SO

The protocol must be specified, as per the answer by @codeer.

I would like to request the syntax that does not require prefixing `https://` be allowed - if `https://` would be prepended by default, that would be nice.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me testing this here on Chrome: [SO]  // [Stack Overflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @Codeer - can you  please edit my question with your test? I do not have Chrome right now.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because i have <2k rep. But both the shortlinks eg `[SO]` and the test you did `[Stack overflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com)` work for me in that comment.

Comment: [testing](shortlinks.com)

Comment: That doesn't work for me either on chrome. Does it work if you add https:// to the link? That might be the cause.

Comment: I noticed as well,  Prefixing http:// or https:// was a workaround

Comment: @Codeer Thanks, can you post that as an answer?. I can verify that the workaround works.

Comment: Did this ever work without specifying a protocol?

Comment: @Rob I thought a did, but I may be going senile. I will try and look into my older posts.

Comment: @Rob I think it did not, how embarrassing. I will transform this into a feature request.

Comment: I guess I am already senile.

Comment: @kabanus Well, don't take my word for it. I seem to remember it requiring a protocol, but I'm by no means sure of it

Comment: @Rob all my old questions seem to have a protocol. For the life of me I cannot figure out what made me stop using it.

Answer (score 13):

There are two main reasons I think this should not be implemented:

1. Some websites may not work over HTTPS, and it may not be evident to the author of a post he just posted an invalid link

   In the current situation, if you post a link and forget the protocol, you will be reminded you forgot the protocol because the link doesn't format properly in the preview. If you forget the link, it formats properly, but uses the wrong protocol, that's an error that's way less likely to be detected.
2. It violates the markdown standard

   While Markdown is less standardised than other markup languages, in my opinion, we should stick as close to what's standardised as possible. [The documentation on links](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link) describes nothing about assuming protocol. If we were to deviate from the standards, that would mean that anyone that were to parse markdown generated by SE (e.g. to automatically detect dead links in popular answers using a dump) would need to deviate from it as well (which can mean a substantial development effort for a small project).

Also, I think the use case is very niche (if you use the link button in the editor the protocol is pre-populated, if you copy-paste from a browser address bar that includes the protocol) so I think there wouldn't be much benefit.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow may follow [commonmark specification](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.28/#links) which doesn't require the [link destination](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.28/#link-destination) any form of protocol. It's up to the browser to figure out what `<href a="stackoverflow.com">link</a>` means.

Comment: BTW, that's exactly what the commonmark specification does https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=%5BSO%5D(stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @Braiam I was about to cite that when I realized they don't follow that specification, since according to the CommonMark specification they should have converted`[SO](stackoverflow.com)` to `<a href="stackoverflow.com">SO</a>`, but instead they convert it to  just `SO` as plain text.

Comment: Well, that's the plan. Maybe we need to check the .net community implementation and if ISS change stuff.

Comment: @Braiam I think they purposefully deviate from the spec to disallow unsafe or unwanted uri's (things like javascript:, callto:, ms-word: etc.). I also think that likely shouldn't be changed

Comment: @wizzwizz4 no, it was intentional.

Answer (score 3):

The following currently does not work:

SO `[SO](stackoverflow.com)`

A workaround is to prefix it with http or https:
[SO](http://stackoverflow.com)  `[SO](http://stackoverflow.com)`
[SO](https://stackoverflow.com)  `[SO](https://stackoverflow.com)`

Answer (score 2):

The protocol does not need to be specified for internal links, but you do need to start with a `/`, though. For example,

[SO](/questions)

which is `[SO](/questions)` This uses the HTTPS protocol as that's what Stack Overflow is using now.

And two slashes courtesy of wizzwizz4 can get you an external link again without a protocol needing to be specified:

[Google](//google.com) `[google](//google.com)`

Whatever gets implemented as the feature request would have to be compatible with internal links, at least as they are used a lot in tag wikis. Alternatively, we could implement things differently for tag wikis, but I imagine that would be confusing.

Comment: Interesting, I would not have figured that out. I wonder why the dv? This is useful info.

Comment: The final link is wrong in this case, leading to a 404

Comment: @CinCout ahh correct, it prepends `meta.stackexchange.com` to the `url`. Likely the current exchange.

Comment: This link leads to `meta.stackoverflow.com/stackoverflow.com`

Comment: @kabanus That is because `/` appends after the current directory

Comment: @RobertLongson You were thinking of `//`, giving [SO](//stackoverflow.com) (`[SO](//stackoverflow.com)`).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I've updated the answer and credited you.